# Javascript/NodeJS: named group RegExp match: what [Object: null prototype] does it mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

see the NodeJs, here below:

```
$ node
Welcome to Node.js v12.3.1.

> regexp = /cerca (?<word>.+) su (?<dictionary>wikipedia|treccani|garzanti|google)/i

> string = 'cerca chatbots su wikipedia'

> matchData = string.match(regexp)
[
  'cerca chatbots su wikipedia',
  'chatbots',
  'wikipedia',
  index: 0,
   input: 'cerca chatbots su wikipedia',
   groups: [Object: null prototype] {
     word: 'chatbots',
     dictionary: 'wikipedia'
  }
]

> matchData.groups.word
'chatbots'

> matchData.groups.dictionary
'wikipedia'
```

The regexp match appear OK to me, and named groups are captured perfectly, but what does it mean the **[Object: null prototype]** statement in console.log node REPL?

thanks

Comment: Chrome console does not show that null text.

Comment: I see, It happens in nodejs.

Comment: It means the Object (matchData.groups) was created with a null prototype. This is useful when you don't want the object to have system provided keys like "toString"

Comment: I'm having this issue, it breaks my tests as the comparison with an object doesn't work. I wonder how to remove this extra part?

Answer (score 2):

The `[Object: null prototype]` means that the `__proto__` atribute of the object is equals to `undefined`. The `_proto_` atribute is used on javascript heritance, so it is used on log to auxiliate the identification of classes.

It occurs due to the fact that `groups` have as keys only the found ones (missing the `__proto__`). And in that way, you can iterate over keys with `for(let key in matchData.groups){...}` with 100% of accuracy that `key` wont assume the `"__proto__"` value. This design may be unnescessary, but it works.

You can create a common object using `Object(matchData.groups)` or `{...matchData.groups}`